# Does Cache Directory gets empted / deleted when app is updated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I would like to know that with iOS 5, will the contents of Cache directory get deleted if an update of the app is installed?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate question of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879860/when-are-files-from-nscachesdirectory-removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrades replace the app bundle, but anything else in your sandbox (like the Documents folder, caches, preferences, etc) are preserved in place. Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks your answer. But can you please share some reference documentation that confirms what you are saying? That would be helpful.

Comment: refer to this, it has everything you need.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5226037/919545