# CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath() returns the CacheDirectory?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I notice that the CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath() returns the CacheDirectory, not the DocumentDirecotry, which it suppose to be according to the note.
Is there any proper reason for doing this? Or just a bug?
Here's the code from CCFileUtils.mm

```
std::string CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath()
{
     // save to document folder
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NsUserDomainMask,YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     std::string strRet = [documentsDirectory UTF8String];
     strRet.append("/");
     return strRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a hard learned life lesson: Don't expect cocos2d documentation to be accurate. ;)

Personally I think the method is just badly named. If it returns the cache directory it should say so in the method name. Especially if you consider that the [cache directory may be emptied when the device is low on storage memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879860/when-are-files-from-nscachesdirectory-removed), so it’s a particularly bad idea to store savegames there.

There are other writable paths, most commonly the Documents dir (for user documents) or the Application Support directory (where you have to create a subfolder for your app and where you should store files the user should not manipulate).

Most devs simply save everything to Documents, which is actually not the place for games to store files to. Savegames, game settings, and so on don't belong to the Documents directory but rather Application Support. They aren't user created, user modifiable documents.

What belongs to Documents would be screenshots the user took, levels the user designed, and anything else the user created on his own and may want to use or modify outside the app.