# Everytime path of cache changes, what can be the persistent path to save images and get them back also?

Tags: swift, image, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a situation. I have to store images into cache and saving their path in core DB. But once i launch the app again, path gets changed, so I am unable to get those files on that path.Is there any way to get them back.?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879860/when-are-files-from-nscachesdirectory-removed

Comment: No answer found here.